# Asignar variable en CellClassRules AgGrid Angular2

Tags: angular, datagrid

Tengo **el siguiente código** que **funciona** pero tiene el problema que tengo que definir ' verde ' unas 20 veces, quiero llamar a una función y en esa función si lo cumple que devuelva el 'verde' o en un futuro otra cadena diferente.

PERO NO  tener que poner 20 veces a pelo 'verde' ,es decir, que si cambia , cambiarlo en un sólo lado.

```
columnDefs: [
            {
              field: 'Type'
            },
            {
              field: 'ID',
              cellClassRules: {
                'verde': function(params) {
                  return rowIndexColorDetail(params);
                }
              }
            },
            {
              field: 'Name',
              cellClassRules: {
                'verde' : function(params) {
                  return rowIndexColorDetail(params);
                }
              }
            },
```

Y así 20 veces.

```
function rowIndexColorDetail(params) {
      if (params.node.rowIndex === 0 || params.node.rowIndex === 6) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
```

He intentado con ... : Y que vaya devolviendo el 'verde'

```
  cellClassRules: {
                function(params) {
                  return rowIndexColorDetail(params);
                }
              }

function rowIndexColorDetail(params) {
      if (params.node.rowIndex === 0 || params.node.rowIndex === 6) {
        return 'verde';
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
```

También he probado Pero string : Lo coge como reservada, también a definir let color : `function(params) { return .......` 
Y también coge el let color : como reservada y tampoco puedo...

```
  cellClassRules: {
                string: function(params) {
                  return rowIndexColorDetail(params);
                }
              }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ver si lo entiendo: quieres transformar esto

```
let columnDefs= [
    {
        field: 'Type'
    },
    {
        field: 'ID',
        cellClassRules: {
            'verde': function (params) {
                return rowIndexColorDetail(params);
            }
        }
    },
    {
        field: 'Name',
        cellClassRules: {
            'verde': function (params) {
                return rowIndexColorDetail(params);
            }
        }
    }
]
```

En algo como

```
let rules={
    'verde': function (params) {
        return rowIndexColorDetail(params);
    }
}

columnDefs: [
    {
        field: 'Type'
    },
    {
        field: 'ID',
        cellClassRules: rules
    },
    {
        field: 'Name',
        cellClassRules: rules
    }
]
```

O, incluso:

```
let rules={
    'verde': function (params) {
        return rowIndexColorDetail(params);
    }
}

function generateColumnDef(fieldName, rules) {
    return {
        field: fielName,
        cellClassRules: rules //undefined si rules no es pasado como parámetro
    }
}

columnDefs: [ 
    generateColumnDef('Type'),
    generateColumnDef('ID',rules),
    generateColumnDef('Name',rules),

]
```

Comment: voy a probarlo.

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias, eres un máquina.